# I have a project with multiple video files that I want to pack for a render farm how should I do this?

Tags: rendering, video

I have a project with over a dozen video files in it.  Now I know how to pack regular images into the into the .blend file, but it seems not to want to work so well with video.

How would I go about preparing this project for upload to sheep-it render farm so that I can get the end result in something less than the 42 DAYS it will take my machine to complete it?

The video files are all in their own folder and they are inserted into the node system as a regular image file would be.

This is the first time I have attempted to do something of this nature, so explicit instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you render the videos out as frame sequences then import them as a  pack? Probably not but I know that you cannot pack videos. Perhaps its like a physics bake?

Comment: Sheep it likely won't work. If the videos you want to embed are greater than 500MB I wouldn't bet on sheepit to help you.

Comment: You can pack the videos into your blend file though. I have rendered random internet peoples videos over sheep it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender doesn't pack videos nor image sequences. If you want that to be possible in the future, you can upvote this [rightclickselect proposal](https://rightclickselect.com/p/general/3pbbbc/image-sequence-packing) I made. But know that it has little chance to happen.

However, Sheep it supports .zip files and linked datablocks. So I'm pretty confident videos should work this way.
Zacharias Reinhardt explains how to use linked assets with Sheep it in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/8I81FohzSjo?t=682) (link goes to the appropriate timecode).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use Amazon's EC2, simply organize an S3 bin and use it. No gesticulating required.